Japanese characters are not bound to angular formControl
Create simple angular project with input control
Typed Japanese characters are not bound to input control
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="title" (input)="articleNameEntered()"/>

 title = '';
  articleNameEntered() {
    console.log('title', this.title);
  }

**# **expected result ****
japnese character should print in console
try following approach
use keyup event for hostlistner
still getting english character in event properties

This could be due to the way input events are handled with Japanese Input Method Editors (IMEs). You could use event to get the latest updated value of title.
<input type="text" (input)="onInputChange($event)">

Ts
onInputChange(event: Event): void {
   const inputElement = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
   const inputValue = inputElement.value;
   console.log(inputValue);
}

BTW, the general way to watch a model change should be like this sample:
HTML:
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="title" (input)="articleNameEntered($event)" />

TS:
  private _title: string = '';

  get title(): string {
    return this._title;
  }

  set title(value: string) {
    this._title = value;
    console.log('set title updated:', value);
  }

